# How to see the request variables or files sent from the phonegap to MVC asp.net Controller

Tags: iphone, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have done coding

`public JSONResult media(HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
  =====done with some code===
}`

Here i m getting the file as null always.
Note:
  file is the file submitted from the Phonegap's JSON method.

My question is : 
  Is there any mechanism for the decoding the encoded multipart file before reading?

Comment: Please insert your Phonegap's Form that have file input.

Comment: Phonegap's File input is getting disabled always in iOS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it :)

Use the request params for getting the file input and changed the method as

```
public JSONResult media()
```

added request.files and stored in HTTPcollectionfile base and got the same file information posted in the PhonegapAPI